# Messed up swap on clean install of Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, xubuntu, disk, swap

I did a clean install 32 bit Xubuntu using manual partitioning on 1TB drive. The swap partition is missing and the large lvm size cannot be changed using **gparted**.  I want to reduce the size in order to create a 4 GB swap partion.  Must i wipe the drive and repartition the entire?

Hereis my `fdisk`.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b367a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      462847      230400   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758  1953523711   976510977    5  Extended
/dev/sda3          462848      499711       18432   83  Linux
/dev/sda5          501760  1953523711   976510976   8e  Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4007 MB, 4007264256 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1018 cylinders, total 7826688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000babde

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          62     7826383     3913161    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu-root: 998.9 GB, 998894469120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121442 cylinders, total 1950965760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu-swap_1: 1002 MB, 1002438656 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121 cylinders, total 1957888 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
bud@bud-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Are you able to boot into live cd and use gparted to resize?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly gparted can't resize logical volumes inside a lvm.
However, there is a graphical tool to acomplish that:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
sudo system-config-lvm
```

Hoping this helps